# How to send JavaScript command when HTML form <select> is chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this simple HTML form:

```
 <form action="">
  <select name="channel">
   <option value="#channel1">channel1</option>
   <option value="#channel2">channel2</option>
  </select>
 </form>
```

and this JavaScript function:

```
/* Use this method to send a command to lightIRC with JavaScript */
function sendCommand(command) {
  swfobject.getObjectById('lightIRC').sendCommand(command);
}
```

I want it so when I user clicks on a dropdown option the JavaScript command `sendCommand('JOIN value');` is sent.

Value is the value from the `<option>`.

Is it possible to do this? There is no submit button etc. I want it to work when the user simply clicks on a dropdown option.

Comment: have you tried `onchange` ?

Comment: look at the change event handler

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar How do I use the `<option>` value in JavaScript? Can you post an example?

Comment: Be warned that in some browsers (older IE), people using the keyboard will only be able to join the first channel on the list, as onchange is sent with every keypress. Removing the submit button completely has a serious effect on accessibility

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 3):

You can send `option` value by passing `this.value` to javascript function on change event.

```
<form action="">
  <select name="channel" onchange="sendCommand(this.value)">
   <option value="#channel1">channel1</option>
   <option value="#channel2">channel2</option>
  </select>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using jQuery:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('select[name="channel"]').bind('change', function() {
    sendCommand($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly wire the event with jQuery and concatenate `JOIN` to it.

```
$(function(){
   $("select[name='channel']").on("change", function(){
     swfobject.getObjectById('lightIRC').sendCommand("JOIN "+ $(this).val());
   });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: VanillaJS is lighter and easier to use.

Comment: OP tagged jQuery in question and hence the jquery solution.